# VB net control form size over different resolutions

Tags: c#-4.0, vb.net-2010

I am working with a VB window that seems to want to resize depending on the resolution of the monitor.

Right now, I have VS2010 open on a monitor that is 1366 x 768. I have the form set to the following dimensions:

MaximumSize, MinimumSize and Size are all set to 948x580.

When I run the app, it looks fine.

Now, I have another monitor that has the resolution set to 1680x1050.

When I run the app, the window is 1263x705.

I was under the impression, that forcing the Max and Min sizes would lock the size of the window. Is this correct? Is there some other setting I am possibly missing?

take care,
lee

Comment: Because the issue is a NET issue and I wanted to make sure C#-centric developers were included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a guess but what is your [`Form.AutoScaleMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.autoscalemode.aspx) set to? It is defaulting to the [AutoScaleMode.Font](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.autoscalemode.aspx) Enumeration on my system even though the documentation says it defaults to AutoScaleMode.None. You may want to look at this [MSDN link on AutoScaling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229605.aspx) also.

1. **None** - Automatic scaling is disabled.
2. **Font** - Controls scale relative to the dimensions of the font the  classes are using, which is typically the system font.
3. **Dpi** -  Controls scale relative to the display resolution. Common  resolutions are 96 and 120 DPI.
4. **Inherit** - Controls scale according to the classes' parent's scaling  mode. If there is no parent, automatic scaling is disabled.

Comment: @LeeLoftiss Glad to been of help